# How to use gperftools on Java Application?

Tags: java, gperftools

I've learned to install the gperftools on my server from the wiki of gperftools and some blogs .
The commands are like these:

```
yum -y install gcc make
yum -y install gcc gcc-c++

# upload libunwind-1.2.tar.gz to /home/work/
cd  /home/work/
tar zxvf libunwind-1.2.tar.gz
cd libunwind-1.2
./configure
make
make install
make clean

# upload gperftools-2.7.tar.gz to /home/work/
cd  /home/work/
tar zxvf gperftools-2.7.tar.gz
cd gperftools-2.7
./configure
make
make install
make clean

echo "/usr/local/lib" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/usr_local_lib.conf 
ldconfig
```

---

And now I have 2 questions:
1.How can I be sure that I've install gperftools successfully?
2.How can I start to do heap check on my Java Application?

I've tried several ways, but they all seem to be wrong.
Thanks!

Comment: I don't think that is actually possible, at least without compiling your own JVM. gperftools just isn't intended for use with Java. (Also, managing the heap is the JVM's job, not that of your application, anyway.)

Comment: Thanks for apply.I agree with you that managing the heap is the JMM's job, but I am working on the non-heap memory leak about my Java application. so I think that it might be work.